# Strange line on Google Chrome after openning popup, how to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, magnific-popup

When I open and close a magnific-popup that contains a youtube video, a line is shown in my page. You can see it here:

[image: Strange line on Chrome]

You can reproduce this on https://demo.socialcondo.com.br

Click on the link on the third panel, the blue one. Like here

[image: Open video]

The close the popup and go back to top. The line will be there.

I tested it on Windows 7 and in Mac OS with Google Chrome.

This doesn't happen on Firefox.

What is causing this behavior?

Edit: 
Thie line doesn't always appear at the same position and have the same size and colors. If you try to reproduce it consider it. But it always appears in the same region.

Edit 2: This is not reproducible in Linux

Comment: Not reproducible, Chrome 40.0.2214.94 m, Win 74 x64

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the try anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You have other serious problems that must be cleared up before addressing this issue.  If the basics are not correct, you can expect strange behavior 
[GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/?job_error=vYD56QfA)
[W3C mobileOK](https://www.w3.org/2016/11/mobile-checker-disabled/)
[W3C CSS 278 errors](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdemo.socialcondo.com.br%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

Comment: While I agree with you, I still think that this error shold not happen. Were you able to reproduce it?

Comment: No, I could not find where to click.  I don't see what you show.

Comment: Scroll down and you will se a blue section with the buildings image and the link to open the video.

Comment: OK then, it does not work.  The link image does not render in FireFox.  The Inspector shows a BoxModel of 0 width and 0 height for both the `<a id="youtube-link" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCVljsOofns">` and the `<img id="video-link-img" src="css/img/homepage/watch_video.png" alt="site-para-condominio-video">`  But it works fine in Google Chrome.

Comment: Although when I hover over the IMG in the Inspector FireFox pops up the image and the 184px x 71px.  So the image was loaded.  And this is the prevailing CSS in FireFox:  `#video-link-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 205px;`  which is on Line 17 of bc42e4e4.index.css

Comment: Just saw it in Firefox and the image is there. About the line, I am starting to think it's a problem with my computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70271/discussion-between-misunderstood-and-joqus).

Comment: Not seeing it here... Looks more like a graphics glitch then a chrome issue... lets be help deskie and say try clearing your cache, restart your computer is your computer plugged in sir ? sorry that was a joke but yes try clearing cache.